# How do i plot a conical spiral on top of a cone?

Tags: plotting

So i need plot a spiral from the top of a cone, can someone help me with my code i have made a similar thing for a cylinder, but there radius wasnt change and in this case i cant figure out how to done this.

```
Animate[Show[Graphics3D[Cone[{{0, 0, 2}, {0, 0, 0}}]], 
Graphics3D[{PointSize[.05], Point[{v Sin[v], v Cos[v], v}]}], 
ParametricPlot3D[{v Sin[z], v Cos[z], z/10}, {z, 0, 20}, 
PlotStyle -> {Thick, Blue}], Axes -> True, 
PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {0, 3}}], {v, 0, 20}]
```

it should be looki like that.
[image]

Comment: How should look like pattern for that spiral?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
zmax = 20; r = 1
Animate[Show[Graphics3D[Cone[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 2}}, r]], 
Graphics3D[{PointSize[.05], 
 Point[{1.1 r (zmax - v)/zmax Sin[v], 
   1.1 r (zmax - v)/zmax Cos[v], 2 v/zmax}]}], 
ParametricPlot3D[{r (zmax - z)/zmax Sin[z], 
 r (zmax - z)/zmax Cos[z], 2 z/zmax}, {z, 0, zmax}, 
PlotStyle -> {Thick, Blue}], Axes -> True, 
PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {0, 3}}]
, {v, 0, zmax}]
```

I slightly increase the radius for the point to make it visible.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Sumit, now i get what i do wrong.